# How to convert *url.URL to string in GO, Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I would like to get the URL and convert it to string. I have to following code:

```
func getURL(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var url string = r.URL
}
```

I get this:

> "cannot convert r.URL (type *url.URL) to type string"

This is working well:

```
fmt.Fprint(w,r.URL)
```

But I would like to use it, not just print it.

What should I do?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The url.URL type has a .String() method.

Try this.

```
func getURL(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    url := r.URL.String()
}
```

http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.String

Comment: Or even the shorter: `url := r.URL.String()` ?

Comment: How do we do the opposite? (convert from string to an URL)

Comment: @DADi590 `u, err := url.Parse(urlString)`

Comment: @Aspekt Oh I forgot to put here when I found out how, but thank you anyway! Might help more people!